# Propagate permissions to subfolders and subfiles

Tags: macos, terminal

I know that using `sudo chmod 777 /folder` will set a particular permission to /folder, but it will not do the same with subfolders and subfiles inside the folder.

Is there a terminal command to propagate permissions inside the folder?

Comment: Read: `man chmod`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `-R` option to make the command recursive:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /folder
```

Comment: That will also change permissions of every file within folder and its sub-folders. The method to only change permissions on the folder and its sub-folders would be `find folder -type d -exec chmod 777 {} +`

Comment: Seems that is what the OP wants... Read carefully: "with subfolders and subfiles inside the folder".

Comment: Yep, I need to read more carefully though it is not a good idea to set the executable bit on a regular file.